# django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'timestamp' into field

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Welcome friends,

Unfortunately I have FieldError. Please help

Environment:

```
Django Version: 1.10.6
Python Version: 3.5.2
```

utils.py

```
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from .models import Action

def create_action(user, verb, target=None):
    now = timezone.now()
    last_minute = now - datetime.timedelta(seconds=60)
    similar_actions = Action.objects.filter(user_id=user.id, verb=verb, timestamp__gte=last_minute)
    if target:
        target_ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(target)
        similar_actions = similar_actions.filter(
                                         target_ct=target_ct,
                                         target_id=target.id)
    if not similar_actions:
        # Nie znaleziono żadnych akcji.
        action = Action(user=user, verb=verb, target=target)
        action.save()
        return True
    return False
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey

class Action(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User,
                         related_name='actions',
                         db_index=True)
   verb = models.CharField(max_length=255)

   target_ct = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,
                              blank=True,
                              null=True,
                              related_name='target_obj')
   target_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True,
                                        blank=True,
                                        db_index=True)
   target = GenericForeignKey('target_ct', 'target_id')
   created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,
                               db_index=True)

   class Meta:
       ordering = ('-created',)
```

I received this error traceback from the Django Shell:

```
 django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'timestamp' 
 into field. Choices are: created, id, target, target_ct, 
 target_ct_id, target_id, user, user_id, verb
[23/Mar/2017 17:20:46] "POST /account/users/follow/ HTTP/1.1" 500 18933
```

I received this error from browser console:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/users/follow/ 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Does anyone coped with this?

Does anyone have any advise for this?

Comment: That's because your `Action` model has no attribute `timestamp`. Show your models please

Comment: Ok, i added models

Comment: If the below answer worked for you, mark it as accepted. It's a good practice in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 6):

From the error it should be something like that:

```
similar_actions = Action.objects.filter(created__gte=last_minute, user_id=user.id, verb=verb)
```

You're querying for the `timestamp` attribute of the `Action` model which does not exist. The available choices are:

```
created, id, target, target_ct, target_ct_id, target_id, user, user_id, verb
```

So, you should query the database based on those (or any relation of those) that are attributes of your `Action` model.

Comment: I just learn Django. Your code works (thank you) but is not functional. Does not block the action for 60 seconds. I do not know where the error is still.

Comment: What error do you get? What do you mean like *Does not block the action for 60 seconds* ?

Comment: forgive me, ALL OK :) Thank you. You are great.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error when one of columns in my second database was removed.

You can try to reset migrations:

1. Remove the all migrations files within your project. 
   Go through each of your projects apps migration folder (**your_app/migrations/**) and remove everything inside, except the **init**.py file.
2. Run `makemigrations` and `migrate`.

Not sure about your case, but this solved the same error in my situation.